# React Script Proxy not working

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

I have configured my `package.json` like in [tutorial](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development) : `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"` but it doesn't redirect my `/api/*` requests to `http://localhost:3001`. If somebody has experience with react script, please help.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did in my case, using ExpressJS as my api provider and running my ExpressJS server on **localhost:8080** also configured a route in ExpressJS something like:

`app.get('/api/games', (req, res) => {
        //some process here...
})`

Im using react-scripts@1.0.7 and point proxy to http://localhost:8080.

using fetch in react:
`fetch('/api/games')`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where I had an express api folder and the create-react-app folder separate. what I did was move the react folder inside of the express folder start both dev servers and make the call. it worked properly.